# Substitute of Lambda, Block And Proc in Java

Tags: java, ruby

I am moving from Ruby to Java. I want to know about any substitute of Lambda, Proc or Block in Java

Comment: I don't know ruby, but Java 8 has lambda expressions, so perhaps that's part of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Java has lambdas. The `Proc` class is roughly equivalent to the interfaces in the [`java.util.function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package. There is no equivalent to blocks, but lambdas are similarly syntactically lightweight.